# Information or Informations?

Tags: plural-forms, countability

I thought information is singular and plural. But now I'm not sure which version is right:

> The dialogue shows two important informations.

OR

> The dialogue shows two important information.

Which is the right version?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Information is a non-countable noun (you can't have 4 informations), so it is neither singular nor plural. The correct usage is "information" without the 's'. More info here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117552/why-does-information-not-have-a-plural-form

So actually, neither one of your sentences is correct. You can't have two informations; it doesn't make any sense. Maybe you mean "two *pieces* of information"?

Comment: I was not sure about the sentence. A native added the s to information in a text of mine. Therefore I wanted to get sure. If I can have only two pieces, then I will change my sentece into this form.

Comment: Was that a native of the country you are in, or a native speaker of English? Adding an 's' to _information_ suggests the former. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that information as an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Kevin; neither version is correct. 
If you’re not required to use the word “information”, consider

> The dialogue shows two important facts.

or some other word. 
(A somewhat dramatic alternative would be “truths”. 
Also consider replacing “shows” with “reveals”.)